# Regex not required

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to develop a simple REGEX in Java with pattern like that :

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[2-8]{1}" , message = "The format is invalid")
```

but this message is still displayed when the field is empty,
so i want to show this message only when the field is not empty (i want that the field is will be not required).

Thank you.

Comment: Please post valid Java code.  What you posted won't compile.

Comment: Do you mean either empty or that pattern by making it optional? `^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9][2-8])?$` https://regex101.com/r/pKrWA1/1

Comment: Hi. There's a syntax error in the snippet you've included. Also, you seem to be using some sort of a magic framework. Do at least mention its name somewhere (or a full path, with the package name, of the @Pattern annotation). There's just far too much missing from this question.

Comment: (OT: `{1}` is superfluous.)

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to match with `[0-9]{1}[2-8]{1}`?

Comment: Do not use `"[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[2-8]{1}|^$"`, it is the most inefficient approach. Use `^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9][2-8])?$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following regex, which matches both your expected string *and* empty string:

```
[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[2-8]{1}|^$
```

Java code:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{1}[2-8]{1}|^$", message = "The format is invalid")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make your whole pattern optional using a non capturing group `(?:...)?`to match either an empty string or the whole pattern.

Note that you can omit the `{1}` part.

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9][2-8])?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FEeCoC/1)

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^(?:[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9][2-8])?$" , message = "The format is invalid")
```